# Creating a view like Speed Dial of Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How can I create a view like Speed Dial introduced in Android Lollipop which can be found when we press Phone icon? Image is shown below in which Contact image and contact name has been hidden.

[image: Want to create something link this.]

Edited:
Till now I have got this much and searching for more to improve. This example uses GridView in Fragment.

```
public class XYZFragment extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();
    CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    public XYZFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_XYZ, container, false);

        //set grid view item
        Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_home);
        Bitmap userIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_communities);

        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"House"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Friend"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"Personal"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Building"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"User"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridArray.add(new Item(userIcon,"xyz"));


        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        return rootView;
        }
    }
```

row_grid.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_xyz.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    Bitmap image;
    String title;

    public Item(Bitmap image, String title) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

CustomGridViewAdapter.java

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Item item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        return row;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imageItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you tired yet ?

Comment: post your code so we can see and improve

Comment: I have posted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change grid view

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:background="#abcdef"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
```

Then in your GridAdapter  get parent id of row xml and set background color at runtime .

Comment: Changing `numColumns = 2` can fit for two. Still not working as like the image above. Exactly two columns are there in which there is very little gap between those. Its left and right alignments are also perfect.